# Differ view data based on recipient for Laravel emails when using multiple recipients

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, laravel-mail

---

I am trying to send through Laravel a single email with multiple recipients, but with different view data based on the recipient.

I need to show, for example, the firstname of the user receiving the email, instead of all of them.

This is the code:

```
protected $hints = [
    ['game_hint_2', 'game_hint_3'],
    ['game_hint_4'],
    ['game_hint_5', 'game_hint_6'],
    ['game_hint_7', 'game_hint_8'],
    ['game_hint_9', 'game_hint_10']
];

$users = $this->users->query()->whereConfirmed(true)->get();

$emails = $users->pluck('email');

Mail::bcc($users->pluck('email'))->send(
    new GameHintsEmail($hints[$dayIndex])
);
```

How do I specify view data for each and every recipient?

Basically, for each recipient, a replacement tag in the view needs to be filled based on the user's email, to achieve a result similar to `Hello *firstname*!`

This is the mailable:

```
/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($gameHints)
{   
    $this->gameHints = $gameHints;
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    $data = $this->__buildViewData();

    return $this
        ->view('emails.hints.game_hint')
        ->text('emails.hints.game_hint_plain')
        ->with($data)
        ->subject($data['subject']);
}

protected function __buildViewData()
{
    $data = [];

    $data['subject'] = "Game Hints! Name 2018 Competition";
    $data['hints'] = $this->gameHints;

    if ($this->bcc && !empty($this->bcc)) {
        $data['userEmail'] = $this->getUserEmail();
    }

    return $data;
}

protected function getUserEmail()
{
    if ($this->to && !empty($this->to)) {
        return $this->bcc[0]['address'];
    }
}
```

`getUserEmail` only allows me to get the first recipient data, but it's not what I want to do.

The goal is to not use multiple `Mail` calls but only a single one.

Is it even possible?

Comment: I think you have to send multiple e-mails, one per user, in order to send a personalized message, unfortunately.

Comment: That means 1 * number of users. That's a huge load of email calls (if there are a lot of users)!

Comment: I'm quite sure there are sufficient ways to pass data to the email view based on the call.

Comment: Yes, it is. But if you want differentiated content for each recipient, that's the most secure and advisable way to go. The alternative would be sending the exact same email to every user with a link back to your site where the info is displayed (and the logic of what to show is managed on the destination endpoint )

Comment: I'll have to agree though that it's not recommendable. What you could also do is queue your emails, which will result in a given delay between the users, but your optimal approach depends on the scale of your project.